# Dictionary validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

What is the best way to validate dictionary containing custom keys with Joi?

```
var objToValidate = {
  "a": { name: 1 }
  "type": { name: 3 },
  ... // many other properties
}

var schema = ?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joi object validation: How to validate values with unknown key names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741612/joi-object-validation-how-to-validate-values-with-unknown-key-names)

Comment: @Ankh Yes, I used answer from there. `campaign: Joi.object().pattern(/^/, Joi.date().iso())`

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `keys` validation:

```
const object = Joi.object().keys({
    a: Joi.number().min(1).max(10).integer(),
    b: 'some string'
});

object.validate({ a: 5 , b : "word"}, (err, value) => { });
```

Comment: Probably, I wasn't clear enough. If we know all the keys in advance, the task is easy. But the question about validation of dictionary with custom keys (ie UUID).

Comment: @SashaPinsk check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741612/joi-object-validation-how-to-validate-values-with-unknown-key-names it amounts to using `joi.object().pattern()`