# Joi object validation: How to validate values with unknown key names?

Tags: validation, hapi.js, joi

I have an object with key names I cannot possibly know - they are created by user. However I do know what values they (keys) are going to store, and they (values) are going to be ISO strings. How do I validate those values? And, *optionally*, how do I validate uknown object's keys, i.e.:

```
 key: Joi.string().min(2).max(25)
```

What I have already tried was based on Joi API docs :

> Another benefits of using Joi.object([schema]) instead of a plain JS object is >that you can set any options on the object like **allowing unknown keys**, e.g:
>
> `const schema = Joi.object({
>      arg: Joi.string().valid('firstname', 'lastname', 'title', 'company', 'jobtitle'),
>      value: Joi.string(),
>   }).pattern(/firstname|lastname/, Joi.string().min(2));`

What I understood from the example is that `arg` key represents `Joi.object()`'s `key`, and `value` represents it's `value`.

**My example:**

```
campaign: Joi.object({
  arg: Joi.string().valid( 'unknown' ),
  value: Joi.date().iso(),
}).pattern( /unknown/, Joi.string().min(2).max(25) )
```

**My input;**

```
campaign: { g_ad_adwords: "2017-01-19T11:33:26.205Z" }
```

**My error:**

> "campaign" fails because ["g_ad_adwords" is not allowed]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this. It'll basically accept any key within an object `campaign` and the value must validate against `Joi.date().iso()`

```
campaign: Joi.object().pattern(/^/, Joi.date().iso())
```

This however will match **any** key. You can restrict this by padding out the regex a little. e.g. only word characters between 2 and 25 chars

```
campaign: Joi.object().pattern(/\w{2,25}/, Joi.date().iso())
```

UPDATE

Regarding [the example](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#joiobjectschema-notation) in the Joi docs, I haven't tested it but here's my interpretation. I can understand that it's not the most straightforward example they could have given...

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    arg: Joi.string().valid('firstname', 'lastname', 'title', 'company', 'jobtitle'),
    value: Joi.string(),
}).pattern(/firstname|lastname/, Joi.string().min(2));
```

The objects to validate **must** contain the two attributes `arg` and `value`where `arg`'s value can be one of `'firstname', 'lastname', 'title', 'company', 'jobtitle'` and `value` is just a string.

```
{
    arg: 'firstname',
    value: 'john'
}

{
    arg: 'lastname',
    value: 'smith'
}

{
    arg: 'jobtitle',
    value: 'brewer'
}
```

However it will also allow the object to have the attributes `firstname` and `lastname` where both of their values is a string with more than two characters. So the above examples could be condensed into a single valid object.

```
{
    firstname: 'john',
    lastname: 'smith',
    arg: 'jobtitle',
    value: 'brewer'
}
```

Comment: Albeit very useful, I think this is not well know, there's a free to use Joi validator online [https://framp.me/joi-tester/]. It's open sourced in GitHub.

Comment: For future Googlers looking for a way to do this with [`yup`](https://github.com/jquense/yup), see this issue: https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/558